# Insert and read blob "pdf files" in oracle database with C#

Tags: c#, oracle11g

I want to insert and read pdf blop to oracle with c#.I tried to do something below.I need insert oracle blop pdf file with C#.I am using this code

```
var fs = new FileStream(txtFileName.Text, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read);
var blobByte = new byte[fs.Length];
fs.Read(blobByte, 0, Convert.ToInt32(fs.Length));
fs.Close();
id=nextİd("tablename")//take ID_SEQ.NEXTVAL
var con = new racleConnection(System.Configuration.ConfigurationSettings.AppSettings["Orclsys"]);
var cmd = new OracleCommand();
con.Open();
cmd.Connection = con;
cmd.CommandText = "INSERT INTO tablename values(:id,:blopfile )";
OracleTransaction sqlTrans = con.BeginTransaction();
cmd.Transaction = sqlTrans;
try
{
    cmd.Parameters.Clear();
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(":id", Id);
    var blobParameter = new OracleParameter();
    blobParameter.OracleType = OracleType.Blob;
    blobParameter.ParameterName = ":blopfile ";
    blobParameter.Value = blobByte;
    cmd.Parameters.Add(blobParameter);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    Result = true;
    sqlTrans.Commit();
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
}
finally
{
    con.Close();
    con.Dispose();
    sqlTrans.Dispose();
    cmd.Dispose();
}
```

so I want read this file from db and i am starting code but I can not continue.
How can I continue after.could you help me.!!

```
 try
 {
    orcl.Connect(DbUser.System);
    orcl.CommandText = "SELECT blopfile FROM tablename WHERE id= :id";
    orcl.ClearParameters();
    orcl.AddParameter(":id", id);
    orcl.ExecuteDataReader();               
    var lob = orcl.DataReader.GetOracleLob(0);
    var pdffile= new Bitmap(lob);
    //
    //how can I continue code here....
    //               
}
catch(Exception ex)
{
}
```

Comment: `File.WriteAllBytes("yourPdfFile.pdf", lob);` is this what you looking for?

Comment: Actually, I want to insert pdf file blop to database and read in pdfWiever with C#.
I tried to do something, but I could not continue.

Comment: "could not continue" doesn't add any detailed information about your problem. Please be specific and try to explain what issues you experiencing.